# Dwarf giant slayers and runic weapons

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

The giant slayers in the dwarf says they can bring runic weapon worth up to 25 points.

The rule of pride for the dwarfs says each rune item must be unique.

So does each giant slayer in my unit have to carry a unique runic weapon? That seems very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

Due to the Rule of Pride no two weapons may have the same combination of runes.

However, you do not need to give every Giant Slayer a rune weapon. You are not *forced* to equip them all with an assortment of rune weapons.

Aside from the fact that spending up to 25 points on top of the 24 point Giant Slayers is a lot of points to sink into 1 Wound models. Also, any Slayer who takes a Rune weapon loses his Slayer Axes ability, which is quite handy to have.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the Dwarf rule-book, but I thought that Giant Slayers(and Demon Slayers) were champions who could be attached to a unit of Troll Slayers. This means that as champions, they will have to follow the Rule of Pride and all have unique runic weapons.

I think the idea is you have a unit of troll slayers to soak arrows/give rank bonus and then add in 2-3 Giant slayers as champions to add more damage to the front rank.

Comment: Can you still have more than one giant slayer in the new book?  I thought they killed the GS bus for some reason.

Comment: You can still upgrade any number of Slayers to Giant Slayers in the unit.